# Grouped Bar chart

Tags: reporting, visualforce-charting

I am trying to create the barchart where i have three date (1st Followup, 2nd Followup and 3rd Followup) fields in Opportunity object and those three date values should show in a grouped bar chart

I have attached the sample bar chart how this should look like.[image]

Can this be done through normal report or we have to go for Visualforce bar chart

Answer (score 0):

Your Report Must be containing Only those three date(lets take it as field Reportdate__c) and it should be grouped over something which have days of week in chart AND with this you must have a formula field which should figure out the day of ReportDate__c (lets assume formula field api is days__c and days__c will be in x-axis). Now ReportDate__c and days__c should be grouped in report. Now select days__c as group in chart.

now you only need to write a code for day of week in formula field.
best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Rudra. We can group multiple fields as per the suggestion above. How can we group with the 3 combinations given below 1) Reportdate1__c and Days_c 2) Reportdate2__c and Days_c 3) Reportdate3__c and Days_c in a single bar chart

Comment: Hey Hi
Sorry for late reply.
but here we having two fields `ReportDate__c` containing dates and `days__c` which is derived from `ReportDate__c` . **Grouping of `Report date` on `days__c`** will give the output we needed.

Comment: I have edited my answer.